# What are the hidden songs/charts and how can I access them?

Tags: cytus

When playing Cytus, I found out that sometimes the songs count on "Chapter Select" doesn't match the songs on that chapter.

Example: Chapter I ("Operators") shows 12 songs, but when I count, there are only 10 songs.

Is that a bug, or are there hidden songs/charts? If so, then how can I access them? Do I need to pay another IAP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that a bug, or are there hidden songs?

Nope, it's not a bug, and yes, there are hidden songs since v1.1 (before the introduction of chapters system). As of current version (v10), there are 30 hidden songs (including 11 songs from "Cytus Alive", a hidden chapter) + 20 secret charts (same song, different charts, exclusive to *Chapter L*).

> Do I need to pay another IAP?

No, you only need to pay for the chapter itself. After unlocking the chapter, you get access to all songs on it, *including the hidden songs*.

> How can I access them?

As mentioned before, there are 30 hidden songs + 11 "Alive" songs.

**Cytus Alive**

For the first 10 chapters (*Chapter I* - *Chapter X*) plus *Chapter Million*, each chapter has a corresponding "Alive" song, which can be accessed by *pressing the Easy (green)/Hard (red) circle on the "Chapter Select" screen*.

**Hidden Songs**

For the rest of hidden songs, you have to do specific thing on the song selection screen. To confirm the hidden song, the ring around "START" text will be colored red:

- Ververg (Chapter I)

  > Tap the torch when the light is at the dimmest point: **Ververg ver.B**
- Precipitation (Chapter II)

  > Drag two fingers from top to bottom, following the line: **Precipitation ver.B**
- Entrance (Chapter II)

  > Drag the left wing's shadow to the center: **Precipitation at the Entrance**
  >  Drag the right wing's shadow to the center: **Precipitation at the Entrance II**
- Saika (Chapter III)

  > Tap both title cards (彩 & 華) to change the color from red to greenish-blue, then tap to start the song: **Saika ver.B**
- L (Chapter VII)

  > Hold the title "L" on the center until the color changes to red: **L2 - Ascension: Act 1 (Loneliness)**
  >  Hold the title "L" on the center until the color changes to blue: **L2 - Ascension: Act 2 (Liberation)**
- ∅ (Slit) (Chapter VIII)

  > Drag from upper-left to lower-right of the shield, mirroring the slash: **∅ (Slit) I**
  >  Drag from upper-right to lower-left of the shield, following the slash: **∅ (Slit) O**
- First Gate (Chapter IX)

  > Tap the "FIRST GATE" title to display "OVERDRIVE" stamp, then start the song: **First Gate OVERDRIVE**
- FREEDOM DiVE (Chapter X)

  > Swipe down the screen. The song title will rotate and change to: **FREEDOM D↓VE**.
- Where You Are Not (Chapter K)

  > Clear the first 8 songs of chapter K (*The Way We Were* until *The Fallen BLOOM*) on any difficulty.
- Music. The eternity of us (Chapter K)

  > Clear *Where You Are Not* on any difficulty.
- Hay Fields (Chapter R)

  > Tap the *Libera me*'s "cross" object: **∞ Fields**.
- conflict (YM2151 Edit) (Chapter R)

  > Tap the title "conflict" quickly 13 times until the background becomes not pixelated: **conflict**
- Magnolia (Chapter D)

  > Tap the red flame above the girl's hand: **Myosotis**.
- L9 : Meteo - Mourn (Chapter L)

  > Clear the first 8 songs of chapter L (*L1: The Devastated Lower* until *L8 : Meteor - Farewell*) on any difficulty.
- L10: In Memory of Maneo (Chapter L)

  > Clear *L9 : Meteo - Mourn* on any difficulty.
- The Ricochet (Chapter M)

  > Tap the blue spinning disc on the android's head, the background will turn slightly red: **The Long Years**

**Secret Charts**

There are 20 (10 per difficulty) secret charts which can only be found on *Chapter L*. On the music selection screen, a letter "L" will appear briefly after changing the song. Tap *the location* of the letter to access the secret chart<sup>1</sup>.

> L1: the hand (palm) of the boy
>  L2: the boy's hand
>  L3: between the wings
>  L4: the boy on the background
>  L5: the hand (palm) of the guy wearing red shirt
>  L6: the hand with the red cross
>  L7: the shoulder of the girl
>  L8: the white shirt of the boy
>  L9: the end of the sword
>  L10: the center of the sword

<sup>Reference: [Cytus Wikia](http://cytus.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Hidden_Songs)</sup>

<sup>1</sup> original charts on v9.0